# API ou base de dados para conseguir latitude e longitude

Tags: javascript, api, cep, geolocalização

Preciso saber a `latitude` e `longitude` de um local buscando pelo `CEP` ou qualquer outra opção que me disponibilizar, não pode ser a do `Google maps`.

Alguém conhece alguma `API` ou `base de dados`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei como fazer, existe ess API OSRM e Nominatim, eles fazem  o mesmo  Google maps, mas e de Open Source. Configurei um docker para ele e esta funcionando perfeitamnte.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

Geolocalização pelo CEP ? Não faz muito sentido, geolocalização é o próprio nome, uma localização, um CEP, possui uma área, não um ponto, latitude e longitude vão te dar um ponto.

Pelo CEP, você vai precisar de uma base de dados, [aqui](https://downloads.ibge.gov.br/downloads_top.php) você encontra as bases pra fazer, o que você quiser.

Você também pode usar o .geolocation do javascript, mas nesse caso, o CEP não importa pra nada, [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Using_geolocation)  você encontra a documentação traduzida, essa funcionalidade é relativamente simples pra fins simples e complexa a fins complexos, depende de autorização do usuário, e você pode infringir meios legais sem nem perceber, então é bom ter atenção.

Comment: exatamente geolocalização ou localização geografica, cep e o nome do local não são codernadas geograficas, eu precizo das cordenadas, latitude e longetude, eu sei que preciso de uma base, queso saber se ja existe uma base, a que você mandou não contem essas informações

Comment: Não existe, ou usa a do google, ou tenta usar essa função nativa do javascript, a geolocation, ou paga alguma empresa de geolocalização, nunca vi e acho que não existe uma api de geolocalização publica, o que pode fazer é captar o IP e usar algum localizador de IP, mas a localização é aproximada, muitas vezes longe do ponto exato.